# How can I force the Chooser in this style of a share intent in Unity - Android?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, unity-game-engine, share

I have managed to utilize some code I found on [this website](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/unity-share-text-message-game-link-android.html) to make a button in one of my games bring up the android share dialog.

The Code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ShareApp : MonoBehaviour {

string subject = "eg. subject";
string body = "eg. body text";

public void shareText()
    {
        //execute the below lines if being run on a Android device
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        //Reference of AndroidJavaClass class for intent
        AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
        //Reference of AndroidJavaObject class for intent
        AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject ("android.content.Intent");
        //call setAction method of the Intent object created
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
        //set the type of sharing that is happening
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");
        //add data to be passed to the other activity i.e., the data to be sent
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);
        //get the current activity
        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        //start the activity by sending the intent data
        currentActivity.Call ("startActivity", intentObject);
        #endif
    }
    }
```

My question is, when the code initiates in an app, it pulls up the android chooser, but also allows the user to set an app as default, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way, with modification to this above code, I can force the share intent to ALWAYS bring up the chooser instead?

I have found references to something called Intent.createChooser() but have absolutely no idea how to go about using it with the above code. I would greatly appreciate some help and even if possible some basic explanation as to the difference between the above code and the code on the [Android developers pages](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) outlining the sharing intent.

EDIT 3.25pm 06-24-2015*

I have tried using this code in various methods in my function

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But I just can't seem to wrap my head around exactly how it works, or what it's doing, which is making it really difficult to understand why the other code works. It appears I have reached some kind of logic gap and could really use some help understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Using some direction from this website [here](http://www.daniel4d.com/blog/sharing-image-unity-android/) I found that changing the last line of the code from:

```
currentActivity.Call ("startActivity", intentObject);
```

To:

```
AndroidJavaObject jChooser = intentClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("createChooser", intentObject, "Share Via");
currentActivity.Call("startActivity", jChooser);
```

Gives me the desired result and does not ask the user to set a default app. :) I hope this helps someone else.